# Swipe to delete crashes when tapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        PFObject *object = [_tdlArray objectAtIndex:(_tdlArray.count - indexPath.row -1)];
        [object deleteInBackground];

        //found the code for removing a row.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [tableView reloadData];
        [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (!succeeded){

                [tableView reloadData];

            }

        }];

    }

}
```

I am able to successfully remove the data, but my app would crash every time I tap on the delete button. I think it has something to do with the `[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]`

These are the error message

```
Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:]
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

Comment: Are you updating your internal state so that [`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:) returns the correct number of things when asked?

Comment: You are deleting the object in a background thread but calling deleteRowsAtIndexPath immediately. You need to use the call back and call  deleteRowsAtIndexPath once the object has been successfully deleted.

Comment: @beyowulf Sorry I don't get what you're saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete the object then reload the data. Don't dispatch asynchronously the object to be deleted then tell the tableview you're deleting rows because the object has likely not been deleted yet, hence the error you're getting. Use the callback block to update the tableview after the object has been removed that way you can be sure that the object has been deleted. Also if you have a local store of the data that not bound to the data on the server, you need to remove the object from there as well.

```
   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
            //not sure how you're calculating the index here
            PFObject *object = [_tdlArray objectAtIndex:(_tdlArray.count - indexPath.row -1)];
            NSMutableArray *mutArray = [_tdlArray mutableCopy];
            [mutArray removeObject:object];
            _tdlArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:mutArray];
            [object deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!succeeded){
                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
                    [tableView reloadData];

                }

            }];

        }

    }
```

Comment: Actually, I don't get an error but it doesnt delete the row.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you put some breakpoints in or NSLog some things to see if the completion block ever gets called?

Comment: The new code you had worked out great! I kinda had the feeling that it had something to do with the NSArray thing I just didnt know how to write it or how the logic works. But thanks !